# How to Filter Aggregated Results in Elasticsearch for List Type Field Used in Field Aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to do aggregation on the list field in elasticsearch. But while doing same, as this is list field if there is other value along with searched value inside the list then aggregation will also give those in the result. Is there any way to filter this aggregation results to get only matching records. **Also want this to work with pagination as well**.

Example:

Doc:

```
{
id: 1,
field: [foo, bar, foobar]
},
{
id: 2,
field: [foo]
},
{
id: 3,
field: [foo, foobar]
}
```

ES query:

```
{
  "aggFilter": {
    "filter": {
      "terms": {
        "field": [
          "foo"
        ],
        "boost": 1
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "fieldAggregation0": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "field",
          "size": 1000,
          "min_doc_count": 1,
          "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
          "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
          "order": [
            {
              "_count": "desc"
            },
            {
              "_key": "asc"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "_key" : "foo",
    "doc_count" : 3
},
{
    "_key" : "foobar",
    "doc_count" : 2,
},
{
    "_key" : "bar",
    "doc_count" : 1
}
```

Expecting:

```
{
    "_key" : "foo",
    "doc_count" : 3
}
```

Tried with bucket_selector but it gives error that value to be filtered(value at bucket_path) should be numeric and in my case I want to filter _key which is string.

Answer (score 0):

The `terms` aggregation has the `include` parameter to filter terms (`exclude` as well)

Documents

```
POST /filter_array_items/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"id":"1","field":["foo","bar","foobar"]}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"id":"2","field":["foo"]}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"id":"3","field":["foo","foobar"]}
```

Modified query

```
GET /filter_array_items/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "field": [
                "foo"
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "fieldAggregation0": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "field.keyword",
                "size": 1000,
                "include": "foo",
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                "order": [
                    {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "fieldAggregation0" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "foo",
                    "doc_count" : 3
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I use the `terms` query to filter documents for aggregation

Use the `bucket_sort` aggregation to paginate results